# Spring Cloud Config Server Shared Properties Across Applications

Tags: spring, properties, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I currently have a number of deployable applications that work in a distributed fashion to solve a business problem. We are currently using a number of property configuration files to provide changing configuration per environment based off a system environment variable. All these deployable application share common configuration for database and messaging. This is currently achieved by picking up property files from the class path and having both deployed apps share a common jar for each connection (db, jms) containing property files.

I am looking to start using Spring Config Server to externalize this configuration if possible. I have a question about how to share this common config.

Currently it looks something like this:-

Web1
 - database
 - jms

Messaging1
 - database
 - jms

In this situation both deployed apps share the same connections and these connections change per environment (lab, prf, prd, etc). How can I achieve the same with the Spring Configuration Server where I have app config for each deployable app?

Application.yml
Web1.yml
Web1-dev.yml
Messaging1.yml
Messaging1-dev.yml

If a connection property changed for an environment I would need to make the change to each deployable app configuration rather than making it just once.

Is there currently anyway to achieve this? Am I just missing a simple point?

Comment: I have the same problem and wondering if it is really so uncommun to have multiple applications share parts of there configs.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555232/loading-multiple-properties-with-config-server

Answer (score 13):

I found working solution here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html, paragraph "2.1.5 Sharing Configuration With All Applications". It says:

> With file-based (i.e. git, svn and native) repositories, resources
>   with file names in application* are shared between all client
>   applications (so application.properties, application.yml,
>   application-*.properties etc.). You can use resources with these file
>   names to configure global defaults and have them overridden by
>   application-specific files as necessary.

You should create application.properties or application.yml at the top level of configuration repository (if it is git or svn based). Don't forget to **commit** the changes.

Comment: Works good also with database repo. Just set "application" as the value of the application column.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this means that if I set properties in application-dev.yaml, all my applications using the dev profile will inherit those properties, right?

Comment: @Ronen Does the same thing apply for profile? Just set the profile field equal to "profile" to have it apply to all profiles?

Comment: Anybody wondering the same thing... profile needs to be inserted as 'default' in order for it to apply to all profiles

Comment: @RobOhRob, No, to apply for all profiles you need to set the profile to "default"

Comment: I know this is an old post but if anyone is still looking for this, you can also use service (i.e. application) names as sub-directories in the config repository (you don't have to place everything at the top level), you can do so by adding `search-paths: '{application}'` in the config server *application.yml*. [Here](https://gist.github.com/emrekgn/93fab341cbe29ea54e866e51001a5f5c#file-a-spring-cloud-config-server-application-yml-L14) is a full example.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I have configured for my setup.

**1** All Common properties across all services and environments will be in `root->application.properties files`

**2** All Common properties across all environments specific to service will be `root->service-X.properties files`

**3:** Similarly, to have common properties across specific environment use `env->application.properties` file

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri:[git repo]
          search-paths: /,/{profile}/
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add your configuration? (or at least a MWE)

Comment: What configurations you are looking ?

Comment: I meant the whole `[Git repo]` example with all the configuration files exemplified.

Comment: https://github.com/nirajsonawane/Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Demo this is my sample POC but not surethis is what you are looking

Answer (score 3):

Finally found a solution. It's buried in the issues at github ...

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/32

It worked liked described. I only noticed, that you need to put the files in a /config folder to make it work. If you put it in the root the file ist used by the configserver itself and is not included in the config requests.

Answer (score 3):

1. `application.properties/application.yml` will be shared across all applications.
2. `application-DEV.properties/application-DEV.yml` will be shared across all `DEV` environment applications. You can replace `DEV` with any `spring` profile.
3. `{applicationName}.properties/{applicationName}.yml` will be shared across the give application.

Comment: can you please share your configuration

Answer (score 0):

For folks trying the non-git approach ,Here is the application.properties of my **cloud-config** application

```
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=cloud-config
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:./app- 
config,classpath:/app-config
```

I created `application.properties` in the **app-config** folder under my resources section. It also works with profiles. ex: application-prod.properties