# loading multiple properties with config-server

Tags: spring-cloud, configuration-files, spring-cloud-config

I have successfully tested loading properties from SVN repository, currently in my config server i have provided the URI and default-label: trunk and i have application specific property under `trunk`. below is the contents of my consuming application's `application.yml` and able to pull the properties successfully

```
spring:
  application:
    name: foo-development
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:${config.port:8888}
```

now i have a shared property in different folder thats shared across other applications as well, so how do i load this into my application along with my application specific

Answer (score 4):

You can create a general application.yml in the root folder of SVN.

See the example config repo here:
https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo

And here is an example consumer
https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/customers-stores/blob/master/rest-microservices-store/src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml

The customer-stores project will read from application.yml and also from stores.yml in the repo.

To confirm, check the /env URL if you have actuator added and you should see two configService entries

Comment: Thanks for your input, Hope you are you referring to the application.yml under https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo/blob/master/application.yml

Answer (score 4):

The `spring.cloud.config.name` property allows you to specify multiple application names separated by a comma, so all you have to do is change your application.yml to

```
spring:
  application:
    name: foo-development
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:${config.port:8888}
      name: foo-development,myshared
```

This will load both `foo-development` properties as well as `myshared` properties.