# Spring cloud config shared property between microservices

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud-config

- cloud-config

  - src

    - main

      - java
      - resources

        - config

          - microservice.yml
          - tons of microservices here..
        - application.yml

File **application.yml** contains property

```
databaseIp=10.20.30.40
```

File **microservice.yml** contains property

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=${databaseIp}:27017
```

My problem is databaseIp doesn't change to 10.20.30.40

I don't want to rewrite database ip to each microservice. How can i reach my goal?

Comment: Take a look at these two Github posts - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/618 and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/32

Comment: And similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781981/spring-cloud-config-server-shared-properties-across-applications